# Can not create a network connection in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

This is Eclipse Juno.

for a Maven plugin, I get errors of the form:

```
ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 ...
```

for Eclipse marketplace, I get:

```
MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
Cannot complete request to ...
```

I have turned off the firewall both on my computer and at the router, I do not have a proxy, the Internet Options proxy box is unchecked.  Putting the web addresses above in my browser (on the same box) returns the correct contents, however, Eclipse doesn't seem to want to contact external servers.  What should I change?  Help!

edit: my Preferences -> General -> Network Connection -> Provider is set to Direct (not that it matters, setting it to native doesn't work either)

edit2: mvn clean install from the commannd line works just fine and downloads everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh wow, absolute craziness.  It's a windows/IPV6 issue with JDK7.

see:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7115226

and

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696

which can be solved by adding -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in eclipse.ini.

As to why my command line was working?  I didn't update JAVA_HOME when I installed JDK7, and changed the vm setting in eclipse.ini.  In other words, my command line was running against JDK6...

Comment: I have problems of updating Eclipse 4.2 Juno. I tried 32 bit and 64 bit jdk 7 with 32 and 64 bit version - no hope until I tried to start eclipse with that option eclipse -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: I upgraded my JDK from 6 to 7 and hit the same problem (using Kepler), this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Note: proxy could be configures somewhere other than the internet options wizard

It has something to do with file named settings.xml

to find the settings.xml file open Window>Preferences>Maven>User Settings

the file in the field User Settings determines the place of the settings file

you mentioned you had no proxy, so make sure this file has no proxy info, if you have proxy settings by any means the proxy info should be mentioned in this file

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>[proxy id]</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>[host]</host>
        <port>[port]</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>
            [urls to be skipped separated by '|']
        </nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

I hope this could help with you issue

Comment: my settings.xml file has <proxies />, and since mvn from command line works, I assume it's reading correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help more on this